# Prove that $(n+2) \nmid \sum_{i=1}^n i^{1987}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I proved that it is divisible by $(n+1)$ by basic rules, and $(n+1)$ and $(n+2)$ are coprime numbers. What do I do next?